# How do i check if my user is admin in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

User has many profiles such has admin and merchant etc in my rails db schema. Now how do i write code to check if current user is admin ? 
More info : User table is separate and profile table is separate. They are linked in user model through has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles

Here is my schema :

```
 create_table "profiles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",        null: false
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
 end

  add_index "profiles", ["name"], name: "index_profiles_on_name", unique:     true, using: :btree

  create_table "profiles_roles", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "profile_id"
    t.integer "role_id"
  end

  create_table "profiles_users", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "profile_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "role_types", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "roles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",         null: false
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "role_type_id"
    t.string   "display_name"
  end

  add_index "roles", ["name"], name: "index_roles_on_name", unique: true, using: :btree

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "username",                       default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",             default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "email",                          default: ""
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                  default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "msisdn"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "address"
    t.integer  "e_bills_count",                  default: 0
    t.string   "notification_url"
    t.string   "notification_params",            default: [],                     array: true
    t.boolean  "notification_post",              default: true
    t.string   "legal_info"
    t.string   "greeting_message"
    t.boolean  "email_notification",             default: false
    t.string   "website"
    t.string   "logo"
    t.string   "signature"
    t.string   "additional_notification_params", default: ""
    t.string   "currency"
  end
```

Comment: so profile has some field in which `admin` is saved.?

Comment: Please provide us with some information on how your db is organized. Like, relevant parts of `schema.rb` and/or files inside of `app/models/`.

Comment: How do you expect anybody to know the answer to that without hacking your computer and looking at your rails app?

Comment: User table is separate and profile table is separate. They are linked in user model through has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles .

Comment: When other users on StackoverFlow ask you for information the correct response is to add the relevant code in the body of question. (click the edit button)

Comment: **Why don't you add your models and schema like we already have requested?** We need to see the whole picture. Not just a few little glimpses.

Comment: @max added schema , thanks to those who suggested

Comment: does that help? or should i add something else

Comment: You have to define some condition by which you can determine when someone is an admin - i.e. 'when he has a profile called admin' - then you can create an is_admin? method in the user class like `self.profiles.map(&:name).include?('admin')`

Comment: I think you are right @axel. Thats the answer

Comment: How can i mark a comment as answer @axel. Can you include that code in your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single dogmatic 'rails-way' to do this. The simplest way is to add a boolean column 'is_admin'. But because this does not scale to well with other scenarios, this is often widened to a schema where there is an extra 'roles' table and a has_many relationship to the user model.

Thare are also gems for more sophisticated authorization models:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization

An example implementation could be:

```
self.profiles.map(&:name).include?('admin')
```

Comment: Cancan hasn't been updated in a while.  The community forked it and it's now cancancan.  So use https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization

Comment: We are using cancan. And there are roles as well. @axel i have a feeling you are very close to answer my question. Can you post some code on the lines of cancan to know if user is admin.

Comment: I would take a look at [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) even if you want to roll your own. Its as close to role based authorization done right as you can get.

Comment: @max Rolify is awesome. I would use that next time. Since we are already using cancan. I do not have authority to change that decision as i am new. I will suggest to my senior. Thanks.

Comment: Rolify is just a Roles library - it just handles adding roles to users and checking if users have roles. Its meant to be used with a authentication library like CanCan or Pundit.